# Word processor with less overhead then Open/Libre Office?

Tags: software-recommendation, libreoffice, openoffice.org

I'll be honest I've run both OpenOffice and Libre Office and I'm not impressed with their speed/resource consumption both of them lag on my laptop and I don't think it's because of my hardware, for example Kile a Latex development environment based on Kate runs better although it's doing, I think more stuff in the background.

So is there another office suite/ word processor for a Kubuntu 12.10 installation, going with Kate seems too low end while doing everything in Kile is bringing in the big guns to early.

I am mainly interested in speed and of course saving in a reasonably used format, not in having a lot of bells and whistles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **abiword** if you want a lightweight word processor. Others like **Calligra** are also available. By typing "Word processor" in the **Software Center** you should find many more:

[image]

Comment: Beware that the current version of abiword in the Ubuntu/Debian archives is an unstable snapshot build, and my be prone to crashing or other issues.

Comment: Abiwords is working well for me thank you, I remember trying Caligra and not being impressed in the speed department, a good word processor none the less.

Comment: Be aware though that documents processed with Abiword might not be usable through other common word processors. When I save a document as open document (.odt) with Abiword, Libreoffice does not show it formatted correctly. On the other hand, I recently received a document that LibreOffice could not even open but Abiword showed it without any problem. So cautiously +1 for Abiword.

Answer (score 1):

It's not for everyone, but you can consider going web-based. Google Drive (formerly google docs) works for me, especially the quick-edit on my laptop. It has the added benifit of not leaving my files on my laptop, which is at risk of being left in the train, stolen, and stuff like that.

Obligatory, but probably superfluous link: https://drive.google.com/

Comment: Thanks but in my case I find the time to fire up the word processor and start writing exactly when the net is down.

Comment: There is "offline access", though I only tried that once for my mail, but maybe you can check that out? https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375012